# warnings emitted during 'easy_install'

Tags: python, warnings, easy-install

When I `easy_install` some python modules, warnings such as:

```
<some module>: module references __file__
<some module>: module references __path__
<some module>: module MAY be using inspect.trace
<some module>: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
```

sometimes get emitted.

Where (what package / source file) do these messages come from? Why is referencing `__file__` or `__path__` considered a bad thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`easy_install` doesn't like use of `__file__` and `__path__` not so much because they're dangerous, but because packages that use them almost always fail to run out of zipped eggs.

`easy_install` is warning because it'll install "less efficiently" into an unzipped directory instead of a zipped egg.

In practice, I'm usually glad when the zip_safe check fails, because then if I need to dive into the source of a module it's a ton easier.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about it.  As durin42 notes, this just means that setuptools won't zip the egg when it puts it into site packages.  If you don't want to see these messages, I believe you can just use the `-Z` flag to `easy_install`.  That will make it always unzip the egg.

I recommend using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).  It gives you a lot less unnecessary output to deal with.

Comment: In-case anyone was wondering, this is correct about the `-Z` (`--always-unzip (-Z)    don't install as a zipfile, no matter what`).

Comment: Although -Z does mean always install unzipped, it will still spit out the warnings (at least it does for me).