# getting rid of the easy_install message: : module references __file__

Tags: python, package, python-module

`module name: module references __file__`

This appears several times when I install my own packages using easy_install and initial google search didn't bring any success.

I am fully aware that I'm using `__file__` inside the modules, but there is nothing wrong about it.

**How to I get rid of this message without removing `__file__` references?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is.  Would you mind clearly stating exactly what the question is for us?

Comment: possible duplicate of [warnings emitted during 'easy_install'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298403/warnings-emitted-during-easy-install)

Comment: You could use `easy_install --quiet INSERTMODHERE` or `easy_install INSERTMODHERE > /dev/null` or `easy_install INSERTMODHERE | grep -v "module references __file__"`, etc.

Comment: Getting rid for all users installing the package, otherwise I could redirect everything to `/dev/null` :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this page while googling the same problem. The solution is:

Tell distutils that your package is not zip_safe (and that this is ok) like this:

```
setup (name = 'yourmodule',
   ...
   zip_safe = False,
   ...
   )
```

This way easy_install will not have to parse your module and will not complain about **__*file*__** references.